# Communication between threads in Python (without using Global Variables)

Tags: python, multithreading

Let's say if we have a main thread which launches two threads for test modules - " test_a" and " test_b".
Both the test module threads maintain their state whether they are done performing test or if they encountered any error, warning or if they want to update some other information.

How main thread can get access to this information and act accordingly.
For example, if " test_a" raised an error flag; How "main" will know and stop rest of the tests before existing with error ?

One way to do this is using global variables but that gets very ugly.. Very soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The obvious solution is to share some kind of mutable variable, by passing it in to the thread objects/functions at constructor/start.

The clean way to do this is to build a class with appropriate instance attributes. If you're using a `threading.Thread` [subclass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects), instead of just a thread function, you can usually use the subclass itself as the place to stick those attributes. But I'll show it with a `list` just because it's shorter:

```
def test_a_func(thread_state):
    # ...
    thread_state[0] = my_error_state
    # ...

def main_thread():
    test_states = [None]
    test_a = threading.Thread(target=test_a_func, args=(test_states,))
    test_a.start()
```

You can (and usually want to) also pack a `Lock` or `Condition` into the mutable state object, so you can properly synchronize between `main_thread` and `test_a`.

(Another option is to use a `queue.Queue`, an `os.pipe`, etc. to pass information around, but you still need to get that queue or pipe to the child thread—which you do in the exact same way as above.)

---

However, it's worth considering whether you really need to do this. If you think of `test_a` and `test_b` as "jobs", rather than "thread functions", you can just execute those jobs on a pool, and let the pool handle passing results or errors back.

For example:

```
try:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(workers=2) as executor:
        tests = [executor.submit(job) for job in (test_a, test_b)]
        for test in concurrent.futures.as_completed(tests):
            result = test.result()
except Exception as e:
    # do stuff
```

Now, if the `test_a` function raises an exception, the main thread will get that exception—and, because that means exiting the `with` block, and all of the other jobs get cancelled and thrown away, and the worker threads shut down.

If you're using 2.5-3.1, you don't have `concurrent.futures` built in, but you can install [the backport off PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures), or you can rewrite things around `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool`. (It's *slightly* more complicated that way, because you have to create a sequence of jobs and call `map_async` to get back an iterator over `AsyncResult` objects… but really that's still pretty simple.)

Comment: +1 `concurrent.futures`. I never knew - but maybe because they are 3+?

Comment: @naxa: It's only in the stdlib in 3.2+, but there's [a backport to 2.5+](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures), or you can build a subset of it (all of the parts you need) pretty easily on top of `multiprocessing.ThreadPool` (which I believe wasn't documented in 2.x, but always existed).